# Adding tag to logs by syslog-ng before sending to a log collector

Tags: linux, syslog, syslog-ng

I need to add a tag "TCP" to the each row of logs which is generated in path `#/var/log/tcp/s.log`, before sending to a remote log collector.
I prefer to use syslog-ng. Here there is a part of my `syslog.conf` file, but its incorrect.

```
filter f_local (fa cility(tcp) and (info,err,warn,));

source S_tcp {

tags("tcp");

file ("/var/log/tcp/s.log" flags (no-parse));};

#The IP address of the remote log collector. 
destination logcollector {udp ("192.168.12.1" port(514));};

#send everything to remote collector.
log { source(S_TCP); filter(s_tcp);destination(logcollector); };
```